# Get the differences of two files

Tags: c#

In .NET, I need a way to compare two files. I thought of a class, which represents a diff:

```
public enum DiffEntryState
{
    New,
    Removed,
    Changed
}    
public class DiffEntry
{
    public byte[] Bytes;
    public long FileOffset;
    public DiffEntryState State = BackupByteEntryState.Changed;
}
```

The names should be pretty self-explanatory. I thought of adding a State to each entry, so that I can distinguish between the cases were the first file is larger than the second or vice versa.

I'm wondering, if there is a common and fast way to retrieve the byte-by-byte differences of two files. I would simply create a stream for each file and compare chunks of these streams until one ends. Is there a better way, or does the Framework have a built-in solution? Keep in mind that I need the differences itself, not only the feedback that there ARE differences.

//Edit:

*After sleeping a night over the problem, I guess I'm taking the wrong approach here. The whole tool is a backup solution, which will be able to save only the changed bytes and thus reduce the overall necessary space for the backup. Instead of saving a compressed 14 MB file each time, only 200k or less will be saved.*

*But, after thinking about the problem, I realized that it wouldn't be enough to save only the differences byte-by-byte. Take a Text for example:*

*"This is a string."
"This was a string."*

*As a matter of fact, the only change here is "is" to "was". But my approach would assume that the changed content is now "was a string". If this happens at the beginning of a huge file, well, this approach is useless.
Obviously, I need a way to index a file and detect all moved, copied or changed blocks in comparison to the original file.
Phew...*

Comment: What kind of files do you need to compare? Text? Images? ...

Comment: The files can be of any kind, that's why I took the byte approach ...

Comment: In this case can you define what `New`, `Removed` and `Changed` means for example in image files? Or in a `.doc` file? Those notions hardly make sense in the general case.

Comment: I edited my original post to clarify things a bit...

Comment: A single-file library to handle diffing that I've used successfully is: https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Diff.NET](http://www.menees.com/index.html),could be helpful .

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in functionality.

So you have to compare the files byte by byte or use a library that does this for you.

Answer (score 2):

For general case binary differencing, look at [A Linear Time, Constant Space Differencing Algorithm](http://hssl.cs.jhu.edu/papers/burns_ipccc97.pdf) by Randal C. Burns and Darrell D. E. Long.  Also, Randal Burns' master's thesis, [Differential Compression: A Generalized Solution For Binary Files](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.2792&rep=rep1&type=pdf), goes into more detail and provides pseudo-code for the algorithm.

You might also get some useful ideas from [About Remote Differential Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372948.aspx) and from [Optimizing File Replication over Limited-Bandwidth Networks using Remote Differential Compression](ftp://ftp.research.microsoft.com/pub/tr/TR-2006-157.pdf)

For text file differencing, I recommend starting with [An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and Its Variations](http://xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf) by Eugene W. Myers.  This algorithm can be used to diff any two sequences. To compare two text files, generate sequences of hash codes (e.g., by calling string.GetHashCode()) for each line in each file. Then run those sequences (e.g., IList) through Myers' algorithm to find the shortest edit script (i.e., inserts and deletes) that will convert the first sequence into the second.

I hope this helps.  I'm the author of [Diff.Net](http://www.menees.com/Diff.Net.htm), and it uses Burns' algorithm for binary differencing and Myers' algorithm for text differencing.  The source code for Diff.Net's libraries ([Menees.Diffs](http://www.menees.com/DotNet.htm) and [Menees.Diffs.Controls](http://www.menees.com/DotNet.htm)) are available under the Apache License, Version 2.0, and the references above should help you implement your own solution without having to start from scratch.